# ASP.NET MVC Check downloading file for null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, download

I need to download a file. If file was genereted for user early, I should to display some message for him. Can I check file for `null`?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Certificate", new{type=Model.Type, product = i.Id})
```

My action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult Certificate(string type, int product)
    {
        var crt = DBQueryExecutor.GetCertificate(type, product, long.Parse(User.Identity.Name), null);
        if(crt == null) return null;
        byte[] rep = Pdf.CreateCertificate(crt);
        return File(rep, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
    }
```

Have you any ideas?

Comment: I can send post request, generated file and save it in to filesystem and then call href.location="...". But it's not good case.

Answer (score 0):

You can return another view showing that the file isn't ready, and provide the link again on this second view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Certificate(string type, int product)
{
    var crt = DBQueryExecutor.GetCertificate(type, product, long.Parse(User.Identity.Name), null);
    if(crt == null) return View("NullFile");
    byte[] rep = Pdf.CreateCertificate(crt);
    return File(rep, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

Comment: File generated once. All next try file will be is null.

Comment: Then don't have a link on the second view and change the message accordingly?

Comment: In this case my page will be reload. I want to do it without reloading.